# JAX-RS Path Matching: Parent path matches expected children

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus

I have a one to many relationship and want to build a rest pattern to match it.

```
/api/parents - Returns all parents
/api/parents/{parentId} - Returns parent by parentId
/api/parents/{parentId}/children - Returns all children of parent id.
```

However the RestEASY implementation is matching the children url (/api/parents/1/children) on the "return parent by id" url, ignoring the following "/children"

I could always go and implement it as...

```
/api/parents
/api/parents/{parentId}
/api/children?parentId={}
```

but I'm stubborn and want to figure this out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible, and I'd guess there's a bug somewhere in your code. Can you show more of your implementation, or even put a complete minimal reproducer somewhere (e.g. GitHub)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's working implementation of your idea(without logic, just resteasy routing)

Please check if it's similar to what you have since there's no code example.

```java
@Path("parents")
public class ParentsResource {
    @GET
    public String getUserInfo() {
        return "working";
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/{parentId}")
    public String getParent(@PathParam("parentId") String parent) {
        return parent;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/{parentId}/children")
    public String getChildren(@PathParam("parentId") String parent) {
        return parent + "children";
    }
}
```